# Should I prefer glMapBufferRange over glMapBuffer?

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-3

The [documentation](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glMapBuffer.xml) for `glMapBuffer` says it can only use the enum access specifiers of GL_READ_ONLY, GL_WRITE_ONLY, or GL_READ_WRITE.

The [documentation](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glMapBufferRange.xhtml) for `glMapBufferRange` says it uses *bitflag* access specifiers instead, which include a way to persistently map the buffer with GL_MAP_PERSISTENT_BIT.

I want to map the buffer persistently, so should I just always use `glMapBufferRange` even though I want to map the entire buffer?  I haven't seen anyone point out this rather important distinction between the two functions, so I was wondering if `glMapBufferRange` is a total and complete replacement for `glMapBuffer`, or if I should be prepared to use both in certain situations?

(I guess I'm just confused because, given the naming, I would think only the sub-range would be the difference between the two calls.)

Comment: "*I haven't seen anyone point out this rather important distinction between the two functions*" What is important about that distinction? It just means you have to remember what you told OpenGL the buffer's size was.

Comment: @NicolBolas - oh, the distinction that isn't pointed out, is how much more versatility the range version has in specifying the access.  It makes it seem like the versatility might only be necessary when mapping a sub-range, and that it's unnecessary to get that specific when mapping the whole buffer.  (which might be true?  I don't know)

Comment: Assuming based on the tag that you're working in OpenGL 3, I'll point out that your documentation links are for `gl2.1` and `gl4`. Maybe if you find references for both functions in the same version which you are using, it will be easier to make a direct comparison.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`glMapBufferRange` was first introduced in OpenGL 3. OpenGL has evolved to provide more control to developers while keeping backwards compatibility as much as possible. So `glMapBuffer` remained unchanged, and `glMapBufferRange` introduced the explicitness that developers wanted (not only the subrange part, but also other bits).

`glMapBufferRange` reminds me of the options that are available nowadays in Vulkan (i.e cache invalidation and explicit synchronization). For some use cases, you might get better performance using the right flags with the new function. If you don't use any of the optional flags, the behaviour should be equivalent to the old function (except for the subrange part).

I think I would always use `glMapBufferRange` as it can do everything that the other does. Plus you can tweak for performance later on. Just my humble opinion :)